# Select function states object not found for mutated variables

Tags: r, select

I'm going through R for Data Science at the moment, and I seem to be having trouble getting the Select function to display certain columns. To start this exercise, I first need to load:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
```

One of the code provided by the book is:

```
flights_sml <- select(flights, 
  year:day, 
  ends_with("delay"), 
  distance, 
  air_time
)
mutate(flights_sml,
  gain = dep_delay - arr_delay,
  speed = distance / air_time * 60
)
```

The result of this code would be:

[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEpTQ.png)

The columns created by the mutate function can be seen in this image. However, when I tried to use the select function to select the variable **gain**:

```
select(flights_sml, gain)
```

I get an error message stating *Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'gain' not found.*

However, if I were to do the same to another variable (e.g. **day**):

```
select(flights_sml, day)
```

I would have no problems as seen in the image below:

[Results for day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abQJG.png)

I don't understand why this is the case, and would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the results of mutate to anything. You need to do

```
flights_sml <- mutate(flights_sml,
  gain = dep_delay - arr_delay,
  speed = distance / air_time * 60
)
```

To do this as part of your first statement, you could do

```
flights_sml <- select(flights, 
  year:day, 
  ends_with("delay"), 
  distance, 
  air_time
) %>%
mutate(
  gain = dep_delay - arr_delay,
  speed = distance / air_time * 60
)
```

This uses the `pipe` (%>%) to pipe the results of your select into the mutate call, and assigns it all back to `flights_sml`

Comment: I see, got it. Thanks!